React typescript to handle the dynamic useState array data either a string[] or number[]
Parent Component
<FilterCategory
 key={x.title}
 title={x.title}
 options={x.options}
 emitClick={handleClick}
/>

Child Component
import { useState } from 'react'
import { ArrowDownIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/outline'

interface FilterGroupProps<T extends string[] | number[]> {
  title: string
  options: T // Options type depends on the value of dataType
  emitClick: (category: Record<string, T>) => void
}

const FilteringGroup = <T extends string[] | number[]>({
  title,
  options,
  emitClick,
}: FilterGroupProps<T>) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)
  const [checkedValues, setCheckedValues] = useState([])

  const toggle = (val: string | number) => {
    let newValues = [...checkedValues]

    if (!checkedValues.includes(val)) {
      newValues = [...checkedValues, val]
    } else {
      newValues = newValues.filter((x) => x !== val)
    }

    setCheckedValues(newValues)
  }

  return (
    <div className="m">
      {options.map((o, oi) => (
        <label key={`${o}_${oi}`} className="peer text-sm">
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="todo[1]"
            checked={checkedValues.includes(o)}
            onChange={() => toggle(o)}
          />
          {o}
        </label>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

export default FilteringGroup

Sample of options:

['Male', 'Female']
[8,9,10,11,12]

I'm new in typescript and I'm dealing with this dynamic array for useState.
This child component will receive a options props from its parent component, the format either pure string[] or pure number[]. Everything is working fine until I want to handle the toggle event as a filter function.
This line if (!checkedValues.includes(val)) showing me the error
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.

I understand the error cause by an initial empty [] since there is nothing in the filter list yet, but how can we auto initialize the type of the checkValues depends on the x type? Say if the x is a string, then checkValues should be string[] otherwise a number[].
Or any possibility I can set the checkValues to use the dynamic generics type  ?
Can't find a solution after 3 days ...

Change the generic T to T extends string | number:
interface FilterGroupProps<T extends string | number> {
  title: string
  options: T[] // Options type depends on the value of dataType
  emitClick: (category: Record<string, T>) => void
}

Now use the T whenever you need to type of options based values:
const FilteringGroup = <T extends string | number>({
  title,
  options,
  emitClick,
}: FilterGroupProps<T>) => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true)
  const [checkedValues, setCheckedValues] = useState<T[]>([]) // <- array of T values

  // val is T
  const toggle = (val: T) => {
    let newValues = [...checkedValues]

    if (!checkedValues.includes(val)) {
      newValues = [...checkedValues, val]
    } else {
      newValues = newValues.filter((x) => x !== val)
    }

    setCheckedValues(newValues)
  }


Thank you for the solution, Its useful and the child component issue has fixed but now turn up the parent component has an error on the option line:
Type 'string[] | number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
I think it can't detect the dynamic type when doing passing props.

A simple solution - since you don't really care about the type of the value (you're not using any number or string methods), you can just use T without the extends. Another (more complicated option).

yeah, i think i just need this line options={x.options as string[]} to type cast it before passing to child component and save all the hassle. Thank you.
